# Loading of js in MediaWiki extension doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I'm about to create an extension forMediaWiki in which I want to provide a special page that shows a form. For this form I want to use Bootstrap including jquery and popper.js. Therefore I need to include js files in the Extension.

Usually the style and script files are included in the `extension.json` like this:

```
"ResourceModules": {
"ext.meForm.custom": {
  "position": "top",
  "scripts": [
    "jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js",
    "popper.min.js",
    "bootstrap.min.js",
    "ext.meForm.custom.js"
  ],
  "styles": [
    "bootstrap.min.css",
    "icons.css",
    "ext.meForm.custom.css"
  ]
}
```

},

And then they need to be loaded in the special page `execution` method like this:

```
$output->addModuleScripts('ext.meForm.custom');
$output->addModuleStyles('ext.meForm.custom');
```

When I only include the style files (just remove the `scripts` property), then the styles are applied as expected. But when I add the `script`property, not just the scripts aren't applied, but also the styles aren't applied anymore. Seems like I am doing anything wrong in the module definition, but I don't have any idea what.

Does anyone have any clues or ideas?

Greets,
Jakob

Edit:
I forgot to mention, that it seems like it has nothing to do with the js files of jquery, popper or bootstrap, because it behaves the same when I include only the `ext.meForm.custom.js`, which is in fact just an empty js file.

The only console output I get is `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` from the `load.php` at line 1.

I am using Mediawiki version 1.30.1.

Edit:
It works now. It seems like the problem was another extension that had an error while loading. I don't really know how this would cause my extension not to load the modules properly but it did.

Comment: Your resource modules definition seems to be correct, what could go wrong is that Mediawiki already has jQuery bundled, so probably you're hitting the conflict of two jquery libraries loaded at the same time. It's hard to help you without knowing the output of your console.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response!

I forgot to mention, that it seems like it has nothing to do with the js files of jquery, popper or bootstrap, because it behaves the same when I include only the `ext.meForm.custom.js`, which is in fact just an empty js file.

The only console output I get is `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'` from the `load.php` at line 1.

I have added `error_reporting( -1 );` and `ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );` to the top of `LocalSettings.php`. Are there more options for getting more output?

Comment: This sounds like you're getting some kind of PHP exception during resource parsing, try to check devtools console to see the actual output of `load.php`

Comment: Okay, I just looked at the load.php output and saw that the error output was not caused by my extension but by another extension installed. So I removed this one from the `LocalSettings` and tada: suprisingly everything goes well with my extension. So it seems like it was an error caused by mediawikis loading behavior and an loading error of another extension. Thanks for heading me into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now!

It seems like the problem was another extension that had an error while loading. I don't really know how this would cause my extension not to load the modules properly but it did.

Answer (score 1):

`addModuleScripts` is not really useful (also, deprecated). Try `$output->addModule('ext.meForm.custom');`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response!

I've just changed the execution method from `addModuleScripts` and `addModuleStyles` to `addModule`. Now it still doesn't work but also using just the css (removing the `scripts` parameter from the module) doesn't work anymore. I am using Mediawiki 1.30.1. Any ideas?

Comment: Check whether `mw.loader.getModuleNames()` returns the module, if not then there is some problem with the module definition. If it does see if you can load it with `mw.loader.using(<modulename>)`. If that results in an URL being loaded, check that URL - if the JS failed to parse, it will contain the error message. (Normally you should see that on the console as well but who knows...)

Comment: I've printed the result of `$output->getResourceLoader()->getModuleNames()`. My module is in this list, so the definition seems to be right.
I've also printed the result of `$output->getModules()`, which was an array containing my module if I added it using `$output->addModules('ext.meForm.custom');`.
Now I'm not sure, what yout mean by `mw.loader.using(<modulename>)`? Since it looks like js, how should it be executed? Added via `$output->addScript()`? I've tried to execute the corresponding PHP but there is no method `using()` on the `ResourceLoaderModule()`.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Like I've just written above, it works now. The problem was an loading error caused by another extension. Thanks anyway!

Comment: FWIW those are commands to execute from your browser's developer console while on a wiki page.